# Why ld linker return "undefined function" to every llvm function?

Tags: cmake, compiler-construction, llvm, llvm-ir, llvm-c++-api

I'm trying to build my llvm-project, but ld-linker returns "undefined function" to every function on llvm namespace with cmake.

I tried to solve this by putting some cmake code like following

```
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "-I/usr/local/include -std=c++14   -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_DEBUG -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS -D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS -D__STDC_LIMIT_MACROS -L/usr/local/lib")
set(Cmake_CXX_Flags "-lLLVMXRay -lLLVMWindowsManifest -lLLVMTableGen -lLLVMSymbolize -lLLVMDebugInfoPDB -lLLVMOrcJIT -lLLVMJITLink -lLLVMObjectYAML -lLLVMMCA -lLLVMLTO -lLLVMPasses -lLLVMObjCARCOpts -lLLVMLineEditor -lLLVMLibDriver -lLLVMInterpreter -lLLVMFuzzMutate -lLLVMMCJIT -lLLVMExecutionEngine -lLLVMRuntimeDyld -lLLVMDlltoolDriver -lLLVMOption -lLLVMDebugInfoGSYM -lLLVMCoverage -lLLVMCoroutines -lLLVMXCoreDisassembler -lLLVMXCoreCodeGen -lLLVMXCoreDesc -lLLVMXCoreInfo -lLLVMX86Disassembler -lLLVMX86AsmParser -lLLVMX86CodeGen -lLLVMX86Desc -lLLVMX86Utils -lLLVMX86Info -lLLVMWebAssemblyDisassembler -lLLVMWebAssemblyCodeGen -lLLVMWebAssemblyDesc -lLLVMWebAssemblyAsmParser -lLLVMWebAssemblyInfo -lLLVMSystemZDisassembler -lLLVMSystemZCodeGen -lLLVMSystemZAsmParser -lLLVMSystemZDesc -lLLVMSystemZInfo -lLLVMSparcDisassembler -lLLVMSparcCodeGen -lLLVMSparcAsmParser -lLLVMSparcDesc -lLLVMSparcInfo -lLLVMRISCVDisassembler -lLLVMRISCVCodeGen -lLLVMRISCVAsmParser -lLLVMRISCVDesc -lLLVMRISCVUtils -lLLVMRISCVInfo -lLLVMPowerPCDisassembler -lLLVMPowerPCCodeGen -lLLVMPowerPCAsmParser -lLLVMPowerPCDesc -lLLVMPowerPCInfo -lLLVMNVPTXCodeGen -lLLVMNVPTXDesc -lLLVMNVPTXInfo -lLLVMMSP430Disassembler -lLLVMMSP430CodeGen -lLLVMMSP430AsmParser -lLLVMMSP430Desc -lLLVMMSP430Info -lLLVMMipsDisassembler -lLLVMMipsCodeGen -lLLVMMipsAsmParser -lLLVMMipsDesc -lLLVMMipsInfo -lLLVMLanaiDisassembler -lLLVMLanaiCodeGen -lLLVMLanaiAsmParser -lLLVMLanaiDesc -lLLVMLanaiInfo -lLLVMHexagonDisassembler -lLLVMHexagonCodeGen -lLLVMHexagonAsmParser -lLLVMHexagonDesc -lLLVMHexagonInfo -lLLVMBPFDisassembler -lLLVMBPFCodeGen -lLLVMBPFAsmParser -lLLVMBPFDesc -lLLVMBPFInfo -lLLVMARMDisassembler -lLLVMARMCodeGen -lLLVMARMAsmParser -lLLVMARMDesc -lLLVMARMUtils -lLLVMARMInfo -lLLVMAMDGPUDisassembler -lLLVMAMDGPUCodeGen -lLLVMMIRParser -lLLVMipo -lLLVMInstrumentation -lLLVMVectorize -lLLVMLinker -lLLVMIRReader -lLLVMAsmParser -lLLVMAMDGPUAsmParser -lLLVMAMDGPUDesc -lLLVMAMDGPUUtils -lLLVMAMDGPUInfo -lLLVMAArch64Disassembler -lLLVMMCDisassembler -lLLVMAArch64CodeGen -lLLVMGlobalISel -lLLVMSelectionDAG -lLLVMAsmPrinter -lLLVMDebugInfoDWARF -lLLVMCodeGen -lLLVMTarget -lLLVMScalarOpts -lLLVMInstCombine -lLLVMAggressiveInstCombine -lLLVMTransformUtils -lLLVMBitWriter -lLLVMAnalysis -lLLVMProfileData -lLLVMObject -lLLVMTextAPI -lLLVMBitReader -lLLVMBitstreamReader -lLLVMCore -lLLVMRemarks -lLLVMAArch64AsmParser -lLLVMMCParser -lLLVMAArch64Desc -lLLVMMC -lLLVMDebugInfoCodeView -lLLVMDebugInfoMSF -lLLVMBinaryFormat -lLLVMAArch64Utils -lLLVMAArch64Info -lLLVMSupport -lLLVMDemangle -lrt -ldl -lpthread -lm")
```

these are return value of "llvm-config --ldflags --cxxflags" and "llvm-config --libs --system-libs".

The command-line error messages.

```
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/giuniu.dir/source/ast/AST_code_gen.cpp.o: in function `INT_EXPR_AST::generate()':
/home/montyaxn/work/zanka/source/ast/AST_code_gen.cpp:38: undefined reference to `llvm::APInt::APInt(unsigned int, llvm::StringRef, unsigned char)'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/montyaxn/work/zanka/source/ast/AST_code_gen.cpp:38: undefined reference to `llvm::ConstantInt::get(llvm::LLVMContext&, llvm::APInt const&)'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/giuniu.dir/source/ast/AST_code_gen.cpp.o: in function `__cxx_global_var_init':
/home/montyaxn/work/zanka/source/ast/AST_code_gen.cpp:22: undefined reference to `llvm::LLVMContext::LLVMContext()'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/montyaxn/work/zanka/source/ast/AST_code_gen.cpp:22: undefined reference to `llvm::LLVMContext::~LLVMContext()'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/giuniu.dir/source/ast/AST_code_gen.cpp.o: in function `llvm::MetadataTracking::untrack(llvm::Metadata*&)':
/usr/local/include/llvm/IR/Metadata.h:245: undefined reference to `llvm::MetadataTracking::untrack(void*, llvm::Metadata&)'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/giuniu.dir/source/ast/AST_code_gen.cpp.o: in function `std::default_delete<llvm::Module>::operator()(llvm::Module*) const':
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/../../../../include/c++/8/bits/unique_ptr.h:81: undefined reference to `llvm::Module::~Module()'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/giuniu.dir/source/ast/AST_code_gen.cpp.o: in function `llvm::ConstantFolder::CreateAdd(llvm::Constant*, llvm::Constant*, bool, bool) const':
/usr/local/include/llvm/IR/ConstantFolder.h:37: undefined reference to `llvm::ConstantExpr::getAdd(llvm::Constant*, llvm::Constant*, bool, bool)'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/giuniu.dir/source/ast/AST_code_gen.cpp.o: in function `llvm::IRBuilder<llvm::ConstantFolder, llvm::IRBuilderDefaultInserter>::CreateInsertNUWNSWBinOp(llvm::Instruction::BinaryOps, llvm::Value*, llvm::Value*, llvm::Twine const&, bool, bool)':
/usr/local/include/llvm/IR/IRBuilder.h:1062: undefined reference to `llvm::BinaryOperator::Create(llvm::Instruction::BinaryOps, llvm::Value*, llvm::Value*, llvm::Twine const&, llvm::Instruction*)'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/include/llvm/IR/IRBuilder.h:1063: undefined reference to `llvm::Instruction::setHasNoUnsignedWrap(bool)'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/include/llvm/IR/IRBuilder.h:1064: undefined reference to `llvm::Instruction::setHasNoSignedWrap(bool)'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/giuniu.dir/source/ast/AST_code_gen.cpp.o: in function `llvm::IRBuilderDefaultInserter::InsertHelper(llvm::Instruction*, llvm::Twine const&, llvm::BasicBlock*, llvm::ilist_iterator<llvm::ilist_detail::node_options<llvm::Instruction, true, false, void>, false, false>) const':
/usr/local/include/llvm/IR/IRBuilder.h:66: undefined reference to `llvm::Value::setName(llvm::Twine const&)'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/giuniu.dir/source/ast/AST_code_gen.cpp.o: in function `llvm::iplist_impl<llvm::simple_ilist<llvm::Instruction>, llvm::SymbolTableListTraits<llvm::Instruction> >::insert(llvm::ilist_iterator<llvm::ilist_detail::node_options<llvm::Instruction, true, false, void>, false, false>, llvm::Instruction*)':
/usr/local/include/llvm/ADT/ilist.h:227: undefined reference to `llvm::SymbolTableListTraits<llvm::Instruction>::addNodeToList(llvm::Instruction*)'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/giuniu.dir/source/ast/AST_code_gen.cpp.o: in function `llvm::MetadataTracking::retrack(llvm::Metadata*&, llvm::Metadata*&)':
/usr/local/include/llvm/IR/Metadata.h:257: undefined reference to `llvm::MetadataTracking::retrack(void*, llvm::Metadata&, void*)'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/giuniu.dir/source/ast/AST_code_gen.cpp.o: in function `llvm::MetadataTracking::track(llvm::Metadata*&)':
/usr/local/include/llvm/IR/Metadata.h:221: undefined reference to `llvm::MetadataTracking::track(void*, llvm::Metadata&, llvm::PointerUnion<llvm::MetadataAsValue*, llvm::Metadata*>)'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/giuniu.dir/source/ast/AST_code_gen.cpp.o: in function `llvm::ConstantFolder::CreateSub(llvm::Constant*, llvm::Constant*, bool, bool) const':
/usr/local/include/llvm/IR/ConstantFolder.h:46: undefined reference to `llvm::ConstantExpr::getSub(llvm::Constant*, llvm::Constant*, bool, bool)'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/giuniu.dir/source/ast/AST_code_gen.cpp.o: in function `llvm::ConstantFolder::CreateMul(llvm::Constant*, llvm::Constant*, bool, bool) const':
/usr/local/include/llvm/IR/ConstantFolder.h:55: undefined reference to `llvm::ConstantExpr::getMul(llvm::Constant*, llvm::Constant*, bool, bool)'
clang-10: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/giuniu.dir/build.make:174: giuniu] Error 1
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:73: CMakeFiles/giuniu.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:85: CMakeFiles/giuniu.dir/rule] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:118: giuniu] Error 2
```

Comment: Presumably because you haven't installed the llvm libraries in the location that the linker is looking for them. Have you looked? If so then mention it in the question.

Comment: `/usr/local/lib` seems to be the only location that you are looking for any libraries. Are the llvm libraries installed there?

Comment: Variable `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` (which you have typed wrongly: in CMake variables' names are **case-sensitive**) is a **wrong place** for `-l` flags. Use `target_link_libraries` or `link_libraries` instead.

Comment: Thank you for answering. Yes, I have installed llvm libraries and a lot of llvm .a files were in the /usr/local/lib.
@john

Comment: Thank you. I changed CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS into target_link_libraries but ld returns error still.
@Tsyvarev

Comment: @montyaxn Mixing 32 bit and 64 bit can cause this kind of problem. Is it possible that you have a 32 bit program but 64 bit libraries (or vice versa).

Comment: @john I have x86-64 ubuntu and llvm support amd64 linux.

Comment: @montyaxn Well all I can suggest is that you analyse the output you are getting and work out the problem. It helps to eliminate as many variables as possible. The obvious place to start is CMake. Can you build a simple app and link it with LLVM without using CMake? If so then it's your use of CMake that is at fault. Just strip things down until it's as simple as possible.

Comment: @john finally "target_link_libraries" worked!! All I need to do was to shift "-l***" options from target_link_options to it... Thank you for being so thoughtful!